# Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail

Tags: email, ssl, model-view-controller

I am trying to send in asp.net ,so i have a function as you can see here :

```
public void SendEmail(string subject, string messageBody, string toAddress)
        {
            bool ssl = false;

            Repository.EmailConfRepository emailConf=new EmailConfRepository();
            DomainClass.EmailConfiguration e = emailConf.GetAll().First();
            if (e.EnableSsl == "true") ssl = true;
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.To.Add(toAddress);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(e.EmailFrom);
            mail.Subject = subject;
            string Body = messageBody;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Host = e.SmtpServer;
            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
                (e.Username, e.Password);

            smtp.Port = int.Parse(e.SmtpPort);
            smtp.EnableSsl = ssl;
            smtp.Send(mail);
        }
```

When i call this function i got this error :

```
Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.
```

Exception details :

```
Exception Details: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Bad sequence of commands. The server response was: This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error message but I have resolved this issue by providing the valid username and password to the SMTP credential. A valid Authentication is required in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to write on web.config the correct parametres from where the e-mail go.

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp from=from@yourdomain.com>
  <network host="localhost" password="" userName=""/>
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Now if your server give permissions to localhost sender you do not need password and username, but if not place there your e-mail info

Answer (score 0):

I use this method for `email sending`, but make sure your `email user` and `email password` and also `domain server` is correct, otherwise you got an error of 503.

```
public static int EmailSend(string sendTo, string subject, string bodyText)
        {
            var from = new MailAddress("info@asandastyar.ir", "Your optional subject");
            var to = new MailAddress(sendTo,"Your optional subject");
            var message = new MailMessage(from, to);
            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = bodyText;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;

            var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = "yourDomain.com"; 
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            var NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("user@yourDomain.com", "YourEmailPassword");
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Port = 25;
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(message);
                return 1;
            }
            catch (SmtpException ex)
            {
                HasError.Error = (int)ex.StatusCode;
                HasError.msg = SmtpError.getSMTPError((int)ex.StatusCode);
                return (int)ex.StatusCode * (-1);
            }
            finally
            {
                smtp.Dispose();
                message.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

The sender email address needs to have a mailbox. You have to enable it from your hosting.